# rdlc 2022 stuck on opening the file

Tags: rdlc, visual-studio-2022

When I add a rdlc to my project, it gets stuck on "opening the file"
I am using VS 2022 and the Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022.

any solutions to this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of trial and error (and formating my computer 2 times), what worked for me was to start a new project and add a dummy report. After that, RDLC report designer worked for my previous project.

This was the source that sugested this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1190482/visual-studio-2022-reporting-services-designer-han

p.s. It all seems that this "bug" was introduced since VS 17.2

Comment: I was facing the same issue, I've tried reinstalling the extension multiple times, also tried to open different .rdlc file created with the 2008 and 2016 standard.
It only worked after this answer

Comment: Just to let you know guys, that as far as VS v17.7.4 and RDLC v2022 (don't download it by searching at a browser, better look within the VS's extension manager), it all seems that this bug has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

So i have tried a lot of things.
I tried reinstalling the extension, resetting the settings, rebooting, etc.

But it seems it worked after i reinstalled visual studio (along with the extension).
The only strange thing is that the first time i tried to open a report it got stuck for 30-40 seconds before showing up.
After that it opened any report right away.

Have you tried this ?